# How do I type a python function that takes a numbers of other functions and returns their results

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that given a tuple containing functions executes them asynchronously and then returns the results.

I can type the function if I know how big the tuple is in advance but I'm struggling to come up with a generic way of typing the function.

For example if the function were to take a tuple containing two functions the solution would be

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

T = TypeVar("T")
S = TypeVar("S")
Func = Callable[[], T]


def execute_two(fs: tuple[Func[S], Func[T]]) -> tuple[S, T]:
   ...


def get_int() -> int:
  ...


def get_str() -> str:
  ...


int_value, string_value = execute_two((get_int, get_str))
```

How to I make the above logic generic for a tuple of any size? I can't use `...` as
that would force all the functions to return the same type. For example the code below will complain that:

> Expected type 'tuple[() -> int, ...]' (matched generic type 'tuple[() -> T, ...]'), got 'tuple[() -> int, () -> str]' instead

```py
def execute_many(fs: tuple[Func[T], ...]) -> tuple[T, ...]:
    ...


int_value, string_value = execute_many((get_int, get_str))
```

Comment: I don't think Python typing system is strong enough to express this. You may just use a workaround to use `@overload` with something like up to 10 parameters.

Comment: I was hoping this might be possible with TypeVarTuple i.e. Variadic Generics https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/

Comment: if the tuple can have any size and any type, whats wrong with using any?

Comment: The tuple can't have any type, it's explicitly contains functions that take no arguments. I could type that as `tuple[Callable[[], Any]` but if I did that the return type of `execute_many` couldn't be inferred, it would be `tuple[any, ...]`, which is much less useful than being able to infer the exact contents.